# How to get shareable link of a slack message using a slack bot written in nodejs?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am trying to create a slack bot using nodejs. I have a requirement where my bot needs to save the link of some slack messages that contains a specific text. This needs to be done for new messages that comes after a bot joined a channel, and also before the bot joined a channel. 
I tried using search.message api call of slack, but it gives me

```
"ok":"false", "error":"user_is_bot"
```

So I guess I can't use this way.

Is there any other way?

Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`search.message`](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages) method is not availble for bot users. That is why you get that error message.

There are two ways around this.

**1. Use a user token instead of a bot token to call the API method**

When you received your bot access token you also received a user access    token. Use use the user access token to call the API method. (see page [Bot Users](https://api.slack.com/bot-users), section "Share your bot user as a Slack app")

**2. Use channels.history to retrieve messages**

The [`channels.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) method also allows you to retrieve messages for a channel and will also work with bot tokens.

Comment: Thanks! I figured method 2 out myself after struggling with it. But I can see how the 1st method can also be useful. Cheers buddy @ErikKalkoken

Comment: Is there any chance somebody could share example code?